# Gnome "Character Palette" applet alternative for KDE

Tags: software-recommendation, kde, applet, kubuntu, special-characters

I recently turn to KDE, and I love plasma. The only think I miss is the Character Palette applet (http://library.gnome.org/users/char-palette). It is not a matter of accents or so, I use to mail mathematics formulae and so, I had the applet configured with the commons UTF8 symbols I use: ∃αβ∀∑⊦λ≼∩↛≣≠ΔΓψ∊. For some other symbols I just use AltGr+something (like AltGr+I for →), but for these symbols I don't know any combination keys to produce them.

So, my question is: is there any character palette applet alternative for KDE?

Comment: I will really miss that too with leaving Gnome. Have you found anything since then?

Comment: There is a bug report about this: http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190776

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [KCharSelect](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kcharselect/)?
Here is the link for it on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/eo/natty/kcharselect) (natty-specifically)

Comment: Well, yes, but is not what I am looking for: with KCharSelect you have to browse until you get the symbol. This applet allows you to define a bunch of common symbols you use, and they are always there by hand.